IndexError when using UperNetForSemanticSegmentation with Swinv2Config in Transformers
I'm trying to use the UperNetForSemanticSegmentation model with a Swinv2Config backbone from the transformers library for semantic segmentation without using pretrained model. However, I'm encountering an IndexError when forwarding an input tensor through the model. Below is the code I'm using:
from transformers import UperNetConfig, UperNetForSemanticSegmentation,SwinConfig,modeling_outputs, Swinv2Config, Swinv2Model

#empty the cache
torch.cuda.empty_cache()


device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
backbone_config = Swinv2Config()

config = UperNetConfig(backbone_config=backbone_config)
#Replace the head of the pre-trained model
model = UperNetForSemanticSegmentation(config)
model.to(device)
optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=0.0001)

batch_size = 2
channels = 3
height = 224
width = 224

# Create a random tensor with the specified dimensions
input_tensor = torch.randn(batch_size,channels, height, width)
input_tensor=input_tensor.to(device)
outputs = model(pixel_values=input_tensor)

the error that appear:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 1
----> 1 outputs = model(pixel_values=input_tensor)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/laypa/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1511, in Module._wrapped_call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1509     return self._compiled_call_impl(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[misc]
   1510 else:
-> 1511     return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/laypa/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1520, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1515 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1516 # this function, and just call forward.
   1517 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1518         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1519         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1520     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1522 try:
   1523     result = None

File ~/miniconda3/envs/laypa/lib/python3.12/site-packages/transformers/models/upernet/modeling_upernet.py:411, in UperNetForSemanticSegmentation.forward(self, pixel_values, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, labels, return_dict)
    409 auxiliary_logits = None
    410 if self.auxiliary_head is not None:
--> 411     auxiliary_logits = self.auxiliary_head(features)
    412     auxiliary_logits = nn.functional.interpolate(
    413         auxiliary_logits, size=pixel_values.shape[2:], mode="bilinear", align_corners=False
    414     )
    416 loss = None

File ~/miniconda3/envs/laypa/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1511, in Module._wrapped_call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1509     return self._compiled_call_impl(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[misc]
   1510 else:
-> 1511     return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/laypa/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1520, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1515 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1516 # this function, and just call forward.
   1517 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1518         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1519         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1520     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1522 try:
   1523     result = None

File ~/miniconda3/envs/laypa/lib/python3.12/site-packages/transformers/models/upernet/modeling_upernet.py:280, in UperNetFCNHead.forward(self, encoder_hidden_states)
    278 def forward(self, encoder_hidden_states: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
    279     # just take the relevant feature maps
--> 280     hidden_states = encoder_hidden_states[self.in_index]
    281     output = self.convs(hidden_states)
    282     if self.concat_input:

IndexError: tuple index out of range

